# Power on a raspberry pi 3

Tags: power

What happens to the power on the raspberry pi 3 when I do a shutdown from the "Raspbian GUI" or the command line?

Comment: In very short: nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry Pi cannot turn itself off properly. Thats why after a Raspbian shutdown the Pi will
still consume an non-negligble amount of current (up to 30 mA). This also means that the 5V rail is indeed always on.

Comment: do you have to power cycle to get the RPi to reboot?

Comment: The Raspberry Pi has holes for a reset header which might be useful for your scenario : http://www.noveldevices.co.uk/rp-project-reset